# What is a non-real number range and a real number range?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that infinity and complex numbers are not real numbers but I'm having trouble understanding what a real number range and a non-real number range is. Is a non-real number range (-infinity, infinity)? If so, does (-infinity, 0) or (0,infinity) count as a non-real number range? How do you tell between the two?

Edit1: e.g. how do I approach the real number range for $x^3+3^x$?

Comment: Could you provide some additional information?  Perhaps use "real number range" in a sentence or problem?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have added an example  question.

Comment: See [Extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line).

Comment: Have you a concrete example where the expression "non-real number range" is used ? It sounds strange. Perhaps you've only found "real number range" and you are assuming that there is another "non-real number range"?

Comment: Where are you seeing this terminology? Are you translating from a language other than English?

Comment: Well the function you provided is actually defined for all real numbers or $x\in [-\infty, +\infty]$.